# ¿Por qué no funciona este envío por AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, formularios

Estoy intentando hacer una especie de **formulario** que al enviarse no recargue la página. Para ello estoy usando **AJAX**.

El problema es que no hace la ejecución de **AJAX**. Es como si ese código no estuviera, no sé si me explico.

Esto es lo que he intentado.

HTML:

```html
<div id="grid-agregarCarrito">
    <button class="buy-in-page-button clcik" id="pagamento" style="border:none" >
        Comprar
    </button>
</div>
```

AJAX:

```javascript
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".clcik", function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/archivosinrecargarpagina.ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          nombre: "a"
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(respuesta) {
          console.log(respuesta);
        }
      });
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Mira de agregar `error:  function(respuesta) { console.log(respuesta.responseJSON); }` después del success para ver que error te muestra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que deberias intentarlo de la siguiente forma:

> ```
> <button class="buy-in-page-button clcik" id="pagamento" style="border:none" >Comprar </button>
> ```

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#pagamento").on("click",function(){

    $.ajax({

        url:"ajax/archivosinrecargarpagina.ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {nombre: "a"},
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(respuesta){
            console.log(respuesta);
        },error:  function(respuesta) { 
        console.log(respuesta.responseJSON); }
    });

});
```

});

De esta forma le agregas el evento click a tu boton, como dice masterguru, talvez la peticion te arroja un error que no estas capturando prueba añadir un error a tu funcion ajax para saber que esta fallando.

Comment: De la otra forma también le funciona, el problema lo tiene en el ajax. De la forma que tu dices está bien para elementos cargados en la carga inicial de la página, pero no para los elementos dinámicos generados sobre la marcha con javascript (que podria o no ser su caso).

Comment: segun yo el contenttype es para mandar archivos o carga de archivos por medio de JS, en ajax si solo vas a mandar informacion usa la forma tradicional que es la siguiente  $.ajax({
        url: 'php/consulta_dat.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
          act_datos_basic_ins: dato_json
        },
      })
      .done(function (respuesta) { alert(respuesta)  })

Comment: Tienes razon @masterguru, pense que era un error en el evento, edite mi respuesta con tu complemento

Comment: Agrégale una coma antes del **error**, sino dará error de sintaxis

Comment: Si, lo vi.. lo agregue ya, gracias por tu aporte